# Make <a href="local file"> open in suggested program

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm kind of new to this. But I'm currently reworking an old HTML page used internally to access files over a network share due to Internet Explorer running towards end of life. In IE we were able to open files on a network share linked through the HTML with the users current default program.

This was accomplished by defining the link and adding target="_blank". IE then opened the link locally on the persons computer.

Now when we switch to edge it opens in a new tab or window. Is there any way to make PDF files, Word files or others open with their current default application?

Could you for instance call the program and use it to open a certain file?

Comment: Its a tricky one for sure. Been trying to find out ways but i suppose i have to develop some form of new application. The HTML utself is basically just an info panel inside another application. Shouldnt be impossible doing it in another way.

Comment: For anyone wondering, I have not been able to make this work through HTML and i don't think its possible in anyway but more so a security issue between the browsers. For some reason IE allows links to redirect to default application for that particular protocol, edge does not. Would probably be better to write another form of application than a HTML-App.